# What is the difference between unsafeDupablePerformIO and accursedUnutterablePerformIO?

Tags: haskell, io, unsafe, unsafe-perform-io

I was wandering in the Restricted Section of the Haskell Library and found these two vile spells:

```
{- System.IO.Unsafe -}
unsafeDupablePerformIO  :: IO a -> a
unsafeDupablePerformIO (IO m) = case runRW# m of (# _, a #) -> a

{- Data.ByteString.Internal -}
accursedUnutterablePerformIO :: IO a -> a
accursedUnutterablePerformIO (IO m) = case m realWorld# of (# _, r #) -> r
```

The actual difference seems to be just between `runRW#` and `($ realWorld#)`, however. I have some basic idea of what they are doing, but I don't get the real consequences of using one over another. Could somebody explain me what is the difference?

Comment: `unsafeDupablePerformIO` is safer for some reason. If I had to guess it's probably gotta do something with inlining and floating out of [`runRW#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Magic.html#v:runRW-35-). Looking forward to someone giving a proper answer to this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Consider a simplified bytestring library.  You might have a byte string type consisting of a length and an allocated buffer of bytes:

```
data BS = BS !Int !(ForeignPtr Word8)
```

To create a bytestring, you would generally need to use an IO action:

```
create :: Int -> (Ptr Word8 -> IO ()) -> IO BS
{-# INLINE create #-}
create n f = do
  p <- mallocForeignPtrBytes n
  withForeignPtr p $ f
  return $ BS n p
```

It's not all that convenient to work in the IO monad, though, so you might be tempted to do a little unsafe IO:

```
unsafeCreate :: Int -> (Ptr Word8 -> IO ()) -> BS
{-# INLINE unsafeCreate #-}
unsafeCreate n f = myUnsafePerformIO $ create n f
```

Given the extensive inlining in your library, it would be nice to inline the unsafe IO, for best performance:

```
myUnsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a
{-# INLINE myUnsafePerformIO #-}
myUnsafePerformIO (IO m) = case m realWorld# of (# _, r #) -> r
```

But, after you add a convenience function for generating singleton bytestrings:

```
singleton :: Word8 -> BS
{-# INLINE singleton #-}
singleton x = unsafeCreate 1 (\p -> poke p x)
```

you might be surprised to discover that the following program prints `True`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples #-}

import GHC.IO
import GHC.Prim
import Foreign

data BS = BS !Int !(ForeignPtr Word8)

create :: Int -> (Ptr Word8 -> IO ()) -> IO BS
{-# INLINE create #-}
create n f = do
  p <- mallocForeignPtrBytes n
  withForeignPtr p $ f
  return $ BS n p

unsafeCreate :: Int -> (Ptr Word8 -> IO ()) -> BS
{-# INLINE unsafeCreate #-}
unsafeCreate n f = myUnsafePerformIO $ create n f

myUnsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a
{-# INLINE myUnsafePerformIO #-}
myUnsafePerformIO (IO m) = case m realWorld# of (# _, r #) -> r

singleton :: Word8 -> BS
{-# INLINE singleton #-}
singleton x = unsafeCreate 1 (\p -> poke p x)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let BS _ p = singleton 1
      BS _ q = singleton 2
  print $ p == q
```

which is a problem if you expect two different singletons to use two different buffers.

What's going wrong here is that the extensive inlining means that the two `mallocForeignPtrBytes 1` calls in `singleton 1` and `singleton 2` can be floated out into a single allocation, with the pointer shared between the two bytestrings.

If you were to remove the inlining from any of these functions, then the floating would be prevented, and the program would print `False` as expected.  Alternatively, you could make the following change to `myUnsafePerformIO`:

```
myUnsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a
{-# INLINE myUnsafePerformIO #-}
myUnsafePerformIO (IO m) = case myRunRW# m of (# _, r #) -> r

myRunRW# :: forall (r :: RuntimeRep) (o :: TYPE r).
            (State# RealWorld -> o) -> o
{-# NOINLINE myRunRW# #-}
myRunRW# m = m realWorld#
```

substituting out the inline `m realWorld#` application with a non-inlined function call to `myRunRW# m = m realWorld#`.  This is the minimal chunk of code that, if not inlined, can prevent the allocation calls from being lifted.

After this change, the program will print `False` as expected.

This is all that switching from `inlinePerformIO` (AKA `accursedUnutterablePerformIO`) to `unsafeDupablePerformIO` does.  It changes that function call `m realWorld#` from an inlined expression to an equivalent noninlined `runRW# m = m realWorld#`:

```
unsafeDupablePerformIO  :: IO a -> a
unsafeDupablePerformIO (IO m) = case runRW# m of (# _, a #) -> a

runRW# :: forall (r :: RuntimeRep) (o :: TYPE r).
          (State# RealWorld -> o) -> o
{-# NOINLINE runRW# #-}
runRW# m = m realWorld#
```

Except, the built-in `runRW#` is magic.  Even though it's marked `NOINLINE`, it *is* actually inlined by the compiler, but near the end of compilation after the allocation calls have already been prevented from floating.

So, you get the performance benefit of having the `unsafeDupablePerformIO` call fully inlined without the undesirable side effect of that inlining allowing common expressions in different unsafe calls to be floated to a common single call.

Though, truth be told, there is a cost.  When `accursedUnutterablePerformIO` works correctly, it can potentially give slightly better performance because there are more opportunities for optimization if the `m realWorld#` call can be inlined earlier rather than later.  So, the actual `bytestring` library still uses `accursedUnutterablePerformIO` internally in lots of places, in particular where there's no allocation going on (e.g., `head` uses it to peek the first byte of the buffer).