# Aeson 2 malformed field in cross-module import when Strict pragma is enabled

Tags: haskell, ghc, aeson

Please note that the issue described below doesn't happen in `aeson 1.4.7` (`stack LTS-16.31`). This could be something related to `ghc 9.2.7` perhaps.

I have noticed that if I define a simple record in `aeson` and then import it, the record "code" tag is now malformed as "body" in `encode` output. It happens only when importing as a module.

First, a simple module `Test1`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell,DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}

module Test1

where

import Data.Aeson.TH
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.Text as T (Text)

data Rsp = Rsp { code::Int, tag :: T.Text, body:: T.Text } deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
deriveJSON defaultOptions '' Rsp
```

Now, if I import the module in `ghci` and `encode` `Rsp` - "code" tag is now encoded as "body" tag which appears twice instead of once:

```
ghci> import Test1
ghci> import Data.Aeson (encode)
ghci> encode $ Rsp (1::Int) "nyi" ""
"{\"body\":1,\"tag\":\"nyi\",\"body\":\"\"}"
```

I found this when debugging migration issues for migrating from `aeson 1.4.7.1` (on `ghc 8.8.4` via `Stack LTS-16.31`) to `aeson 2.0.3.0` (on `ghc 9.2.7` via `Stack LTS-20.13`). It doesn't happen if instead of importing the module, I directly load `Test1.hs` code in ghci.

If I remove `Strict` pragma, the issue seems to go away. Perhaps something is going on here that is new to `ghc 9.2+` or template haskell derivation in `aeson`?

Comment: I can duplicate with lts-20.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that is already fixed in `2.1.1.0` as noted in [changelog](https://github.com/haskell/aeson/blob/master/changelog.md):

> Use unsafeDupablePerformIO instead of incorrect accursedUnutterablePerformIO in creation of keys in TH serialisation. This fixes a bug in TH deriving, e.g. when Strict pragma was enabled.

So it seems any `LTS` that has `aeson` pre `2.1.1.0` is unusable if template haskell derivation is enabled for `aeson` which I suspect is the case for lot of us.

Comment: Not that this will help you directly, but one of my more [popular answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61024465/7203016) discussed the safety differences between `unsafeDupablePerformIO` and `accursedUnutterablePerformIO`..